# Cannot connect to MySql database: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, node.js

There are quite a few questions similar to this but none of them have solved my issue.

I have used MySql before for college projects so I think maybe the old ones are disabling any new ones, but i dont remember their passwords and cant delete them.

I've tried changing env PATH variable many times, nothing works. It is currently: `PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin/`

I've tried mysql -u root also countless times. The code is as follow:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: ""
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    con.query("CREATE DATABASE ishopDB", function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Database created");
    });
  });
```

I have MySql downloaded, and active instance is always red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of MySQL 5.7 there is no longer an empty password for root when you install it the first time. So if your code previously ran on another MySQL installation and you just freshly installed 5.7 (or higher) on an empty machine this would explain your issue.

When you install MySQL the installation can differ per OS: MacOS, Windows and Red Hat/CentOS will generate a password for you, while Debian will ask you to provide one. See also here where to it will display/store the password:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/default-privileges.html